# Angles of rotation matrix using OpenCv function cvPosit

Tags: opencv, rotation, estimation, angle

I'm working on a 3D Pose estimation system. I used OpenCVs function cvPosit to calculate the rotation matrix and the translation vector.

I also need the angles of the rotation matrix, but no algorithms seem to be working.

The function cv::RQDecomp3x3(), which was the answer of topic "in opencv : how to get yaw, roll, pitch from POSIT rotation matrix" cannot work, because the function needs the 3x3 matrix of the projection matrix.

Furthermore I tried to use algorithms from the links below, but nothing worked.

visionopen.com/cv/vosm/doc/html/recognitionalgs_8cpp_source.html

stackoverflow.com/questions/16266740/in-opencv-how-to-get-yaw-roll-pitch-from-posit-rotation-matrix

quad08pyro.groups.et.byu.net/vision.htm

stackoverflow.com/questions/13565625/opencv-c-posit-why-are-my-values-always-nan-with-small-focal-lenght

www.c-plusplus.de/forum/308773-full

I used the most common Posit Tutorial and an own  example with Blender, so I could render an image to retreive the image points and to know the exact angles. The object's Z-Axis in Blender was rotated by 10 degrees - And I checked all the degrees of all 3 Axis due to changes in Axis between Blender and OpenCV.

```
double focalLength = 700.0;
CvPOSITObject* positObject;
std::vector<CvPoint3D32f> modelPoints;
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));  
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(CUBE_SIZE, 0.0f, 0.0f));
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(0.0f, CUBE_SIZE, 0.0f));
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(0.0f, 0.0f, CUBE_SIZE)); 

std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> imagePoints;
imagePoints.push_back( cvPoint2D32f( 157,372) );
imagePoints.push_back( cvPoint2D32f(423,386 ));
imagePoints.push_back( cvPoint2D32f( 157,108 ));
imagePoints.push_back( cvPoint2D32f(250,337));

// Moving the points to the image center as described in the tutorial
for (int i = 0; i < imagePoints.size();i++) {
    imagePoints[i] = cvPoint2D32f(imagePoints[i].x -320, 240 - imagePoints[i].y);
}

CvVect32f translation_vector = new float[3];    
CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,iterations, 0.1f);
positObject = cvCreatePOSITObject( &modelPoints[0], static_cast<int>(modelPoints.size()));
CvMatr32f rotation_matrix = new float[9];   
cvPOSIT( positObject, &imagePoints[0], focalLength, criteria, rotation_matrix, translation_vector );

algorithms to get angles...
```

I already tried to calculate the results from radian to degree and clockwise but I already get bad results using the rotation matrix of cvPosit from OpenCV. I also changed matrix format to check wrong formatting...

I used simple rotation matrices - like only doing a rotation of the x-axis, y and z-axis and some algorithm worked. The rotation matrix of cvPosit didn't work with that algorithm.

I appreciate any support.

Comment: I solved the problem using the Code from ExtractYawPitchRoll function in LGPL aforge.net framework that works with the rotationmatrix from OpenCVs POSIT. If you don't have to use OpenCVs implementation of POSIT it is possible to use the implementation of aforge.net. This is the whole code to get the angles of the rotation matrix: float yaw = (float) atan2f(rotation_matrix[2], rotation_matrix[8]); float pitch = (float) asin(-rotation_matrix[5]); float roll = (float) atan2f(rotation_matrix[3],rotation_matrix[4]);
Calculate the angle in degree with radian * (float) (180.0 / CV_PI);